# Integrate HTML menu from Third-party into my application

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Some of our customers gave me a link that opens HTML menu (HTML + JS).
I need to use this menu into my application.

The menu location is something like: 
http://www.customer_web_site.com/?pagename=HTMLMenu

When I click the above link, I can open the menu and It looks okey, but the problem is when I put it inside an iframe in my page, it looks very ugly in terms of when the user click any link on this menu, only the iframe content get changed and I need the whole page get changed.

How can I accomplish that???

Comment: Does the menu need to be loaded into an iframe?

Comment: Could you provide code used on the main page and in the iframe?

Comment: I just used ordinary IFRAME, I can use another tehcnique if avaiable

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the links in the menu, they need to have the attribute `target="_parent"` that way the links will normally. I'm guessing you cannot edit the menu code, can you copy and paste it inside your website, that way you don't have to load it as an `iframe`?

Comment: Yes I cannot change the menu code and I need also I cannot copy the menu code as the requirements enforce me to use the link as is in order to get the latest changes from the third-party on-the-fly

Answer (score 0):

Actually I am deploying my application in Java Servlet Container, so I used some JSP tag that do the trick, it open connection to the remote url, copy the source code and put it in my page. it is [c:import](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL4.html)